# compare table structure (not content) from two different mysql database using query or third party tool?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two different database (mySQL) named

- DatabaseOne
- DatabaseTwo

  Both DB have one table
- DatabaseOne

  - DBOneTableOne
- DatabaseTwo

  - DBTwoTableOne

Hoping Structure of both table is same because DatabaseOne structured designed using XAMPP phpmyadmin panel where DatabaseTwo structured designed by writing hibernate class first and than used hibernate create schema tool (hbm2ddl).

Structure of database:-

```
**DBOneTableOne**
Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra
Id    | int(11)     | No   | PK  |         | auto_inc
name  | varchar(25) | No   |     |         | 

**DBTwoTableOne**
Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra
Id    | int(11)     | No   | PK  |         | auto_inc
name  | varchar(25) | No   |     |         |
```

I know one option to cross check manually database structure but it's time consuming and also I need to check more than 200 tables and I don't want to use hibernate reverse engineering wizard.

Is it possible to check both DB table structure is same using query??? Or any other third party software I need to use.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218499/mysql-diff-tool) could help you